# Double event listener for single function

Tags: javascript

With your help in [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/168915/removal-of-jquery-from-script-to-auto-apply-coupons-from-a-link),
I've got this code to show the pop-up, and than hide it when close button is clicked:

```
<script>
    var applycouponPopupId = "popup-wrapper";
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById(applycouponPopupId).classList.add("modal-overlay_visible");
    });
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        if (!e.target.classList.contains("modal-overlay__close")) return;
        document.getElementById(applycouponPopupId).classList.remove("modal-overlay_visible");
    });
</script>
```

Now i need to change the code to close the pop-up on any click or scroll.
According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27029689/7952052), i converted code to the following:

```
<script>
    var applycouponPopupId = "popup-wrapper";
    window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        document.getElementById(applycouponPopupId).classList.add("modal-overlay_visible");
    });

    function mouseMoveHandler() {
        document.getElementById(applycouponPopupId).classList.remove("modal-overlay_visible");
    }

    ("click scroll".split(" ")).forEach(function(e) {
        document.addEventListener(e, mouseMoveHandler, false);
    });
</script>
```

Please tell if i did everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only suggestion I have is..

`"click scroll".split(" ")` ... why? what was that person thinking?

`['click', 'scroll'].forEach()` is both faster and shorter.

Aside from that, looks great!

Comment: Small correction :) it should be forEach. foreach was not working at least for me:)

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Updated answer.